# Как у EditText в JAVA сделать маску?

Tags: java, android

У компонента EditText требуется сделать следующую маску для ввода:
градусы, минуты, секунды.

Выглядеть должно так: 45°25'34"

Пользователь вводит подряд цифры и поля сами должны заполниться.
Как это сделать?

Comment: inputFilter в помощь